# Left outer join null using VB.NET and LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, left-join

I've got what I think is a working left outer join [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) query, but I'm having problems with the select because of null values in the right hand side of the join. Here is what I have so far

```
 Dim Os = From e In oExcel
        Group Join c In oClassIndexS On c.tClassCode Equals Mid(e.ClassCode, 1, 4)
        Into right1 = Group _
        From c In right1.DefaultIfEmpty
```

I want to return all of `e` and one column from `c` called `tClassCode`. I was wondering what the syntax would be. As you can see, I'm using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

#### Update...

Here is the query doing join where I get the error:

> _message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 Dim Os = From e In oExcel
             Group Join c In oClassIndexS On c.tClassCode Equals Mid(e.ClassCode, 1, 4)
             Into right1 = Group _
             From c In right1.DefaultIfEmpty
        Select e, c.tClassCode
```

If I remove the c.tClassCode from the select, the query runs without error. So I thought perhaps I needed to do a select new, but I don't think I was doing that correctly either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it working... At least I get results without errors. Thanks for the help... Here it is.

```
 Dim Os = From e In oExcel
                 Group Join c In oClassIndexS On c.tClassCode Equals Mid(e.ClassCode, 1, 4)
                 Into right1 = Group _
                 From jo In right1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Select New With {.CivilServiceTitle = e.CivilServiceTitle, .Code = If(jo Is Nothing, Nothing, jo.tClassCode)}
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** you need to check `c` for null, specifically the `c` after your grouping. See my updates below.

You need to do a null check on <s>`tClassCode`</s> `c` in your select statement. <s>What type is `tClassCode`? You should be able to do a null check on <s>the value</s> `c` and if it's null cast a nullable of the respective type and returned it, otherwise return the actual value.</s>

<s>Since I am not sure what `tClassCode` is let's assume it's an integer, in which case the cast would be to a nullable integer (`Integer?`). With that in mind your select statement, to be added at the end of what you have so far, should resemble:</s>

Since `tClassCode` is a string your code would resemble:

```
Select _
    e, _
    Code = If(c Is Nothing, Nothing, c.tClassCode)
```

Depending on what you need to do if `c` is null you could return `String.Empty` instead of `Nothing`:

```
Select _
    e, _
    Code = If(c Is Nothing, String.Empty, c.tClassCode)
```

Of course you are free to further expand the selection of "e" to project its specific columns by name.

The important thing to realize is that you must check `c` for null before using any of its properties since it might be null depending on the left outer join result for a particular result (row). Back to my earlier example, if you had another field named `Priority` that was an integer you would cast against a nullable:

```
Select _
    e, _
    Priority = If(c Is Nothing, CType(Nothing, Integer?), c.Priority)
```

Comment: With that i'm getting an error of "Cannot infer a common type because more than one type is possible.  The ClassCode is a string type so i changed it to string but it doesn't like that either.  Says Type string must be a value type or a type argument constrained to 'Structure' in order to be used with nullable.  if you have a second to explain further that would be great.

Comment: @jvcoach a string type accepts a null value, therefore there is no nullable version of string (i.e., you can't use `String?`). That said, I'm not sure why you would be having a problem since a string type should accept a null value. Can you edit your question to show your original select query attempt for `e` and `c.tClassCode`? Also please copy/paste the error you get when you use the original code that is not working.

Comment: I modified the post, hopefully you can educate me.

Comment: @jvcoach I've updated my reply. Please read over it carefully since I have updated the code samples and struck through my older response that doesn't entirely apply.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I think i understand what you are saying.  I've tried the Code=(c is nothing, nothing, c.tClassCode) but i'm still getting the object reference error.  When the "Code" column is added in there that is when this happens.  So i was wondering if there is something more that needs to be done with the select, like the "new with".  just not sure

Comment: @jvcoach to try the `new with` use this piece of code: `Select New With { .E = e, .Code = If(c Is Nothing, Nothing, c.tClassCode) }` - let me know if that solves it. It's on one line but you can break it up with the underscores if you want to. In C# I actually need to project it with `new`, but in my VB sample I didn't. I tried `new with` as above and it works for me. Let me know if that solves anything for you.